# Google Sheets filter with OR criteria

Tags: filter, google-sheets, sum, sumifs

Can someone please help me with this formula on a Google-Sheet?
I am using a filter but I need to add an OR condition.

```
  =SUM(filter(H:H, A:A="completed order"))
```

I want it to include Completed order OR Confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

See if this works

```
 =SUM(filter(H:H, (A:A="completed order") + (A:A="confirmation")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "+" in between of the two conditions to use or:

```
= SUM(filter(H:H, (A:A="condition 1") + (A:A="condition 2")))
```